# How do I get a subscription to WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have the World of Warcraft Battle chest, but I'm playing under the starter edition until level 20. I'll have to get a subscription to play the Burning Crusade and Wrath of the Lich King, so how do I get one?

Comment: How do you buy one?

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade your World of Warcraft account and purchase expansion content at http://www.battle.net.